# Passing data from Activity to Fragment using Otto

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, otto

In my application I'm adding Fragments dynamically to the container in main activity view. I would like to know what is the best way to pass data when using Otto when we add Fragment. Currently this is how I'm doing it, please in example I'm not posting my CustomObject

Inside My Main Activity

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, MY_CUSTOM_FRAGMENT).commit();
    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceCustomString());
```

Inside My Fragment

```
    @Subscribe
    public void onCustomStringChanged(String customString) {
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Methods annotated with `@Subscribe` will automatically be called if you also have a `@Produce` method for the same type registered.

The best way to inform new fragments of data like this is you have an `@Produce` method on the activity:

```
@Produce public String produceCustomString() {
  return "Hello, World!";
}
```

And then all your fragments which have `@Subscribe` methods:

```
@Subscribe public void onCustomStringEvent(String event) {
  // ...
}
```

When you register a fragment which has this method, Otto will call the `@Produce` method on the activity to get the latest value which it will pass to the fragment's method.

Comment: Thanks Jake, that helped. Actually i had @Produce in my activity but i was still manually calling post after adding the fragment. Will remove that extra post.

Comment: Tried to edit the answer to replace "public void String" with "public String" and the system doesn't allow me to do so saying "Edits must be at least 6 characters" :-)