# IllegalArgumentException in OTTO when unregistering the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, otto

I use Otto bus to communicate events from activity to the fragments. The problem is, the fragments are managed by the `ViewPager` and the fragment can be recreated without ever executing its `onPause()` and/or `onResume()`. The unpleasant side-effect of that is that when `bus.unregister(fragment)` is called in `onPause()` the call periodically fails with IllegalArgumentException. I also suspect that calls to my `@Subscribe` annotated method can be missed since `bus.register()` call is in `onResume()` method which also can be not called. And, unfortunately there's no `bus.isRegistered(fragment)` method to do a safe check.

Is there a better way to register/unregister ViewPager managed fragment?

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593086/passing-data-from-activity-to-fragment-using-otto) that discusses a similar setup but it does not include fragments running in ViewPager

Comment: Which fragment pager are you using? FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter? I ask, because I've converted to this method of registering in onResume and unregistering in onPause and haven't noticed either of the side effects you describe using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: Also, maybe some information on what you're seeing to indicate 'recreation' in the line 'the fragment can be recreated without ever executing its onPause or onResume()'? I'm really not sure what recreation would mean without these calls or how you'd detect it.

Comment: I was using FragmentPagerAdapter at the time I wrote the question. Testing now with FragmentStatePagerAdapter. When I'm referring to "recreation" I really mean that old Fragment object can be tossed away and seemingly replaced with another one so for example I've learnt not to save anything as a field in Fragment. Seems the same applies to onPause/onResume. There are few questions that mention lack of these calls when dealing with ViewPager and fragments

Comment: I am not certain, but this sounds suspicious. My understanding and what seems to be the case by my code base is that, when the paged fragments go off-screen, they go through their standard life cycle calls to be detached. Looking at the source code of `FragmentPagerAdapter.destroyItem()` there is a call to `FragmentTransaction.detach` which would cause the Fragment to go through its lifecycle. I'm assuming you are logging the onPause on Resume with a print out of `this` so you can see the object id of the fragments making the calls?

Comment: For reference, I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/campnic/4727711) which shows the output in my log cat of a single Log.d statement in onResume and onPause as I swipe through my fragments. I ran this test a bunch of times at varying speeds with the same result. I've annotated the log output with (>>) and my user interaction so you can tell what I was doing.

Comment: @NickCampion how does it help me to deal with this pretty concrete problem? So far - I slapped try/catch around the offending code but that just masks the problem

Comment: I guess I'm trying to suggest the problem might be somewhere else. I've seen similar problems arise when I had fragments inside of fragments or the ViewPager in a fragment. Have you updated to the latest Support Library? I guess I'm trying to confirm for you I cannot reproduce the problem so there might be other situational factors causing what you are seeing.

Comment: You right Nick. Turns out I'm a total idiot who forgot that I already have register/unregister in the abstract class that I'm deriving my fragment from. So the unregister is executed twice and that is a source of failure. Thanks a lot for making me think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you came here because you have a similar issue - turns out (thanks Nick Campion for pointing it) there's nothing wrong with `onPause\onResume` in my fragment. I simply had `register/untegister` called twice: once in the parent abstract class and another one in the child. As in `class MyFragment extends AbsFragment`. So perhaps look at your code